# Problematic json_query syntax error on a field containing either all numeric values or non-numeric values

Tags: ansible, json-query

When I execute the ansible task, I get the following:

> fatal: [baseserver2.jlhimpel.net]: FAILED! => {"msg": "JMESPathError in json_query filter plugin:\ninvalid token: Parse error at column 59, token "32" (NUMBER), for expression:\n"repository[?os==fedora && architecture==x86_64 && release==32].{repoUrl: repoUrl}"\n

I'm not sure how to correct the syntax error.  Also, please note that the value of `release` may be all numeric or may be non-numeric (Note difference between "fedora" values and "ubuntu" values.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

*defaults/main.xml*

```yaml
distributionRepositoryUrl:
  repository:
    - os: fedora
      architecture: aarch64
      release: 32
      repoUrl: https://download.fedoraproject.org:/pub/fedora/linux/releases/32/Server/aarch64/os/
    - os: fedora
      architecture: x86_64
      release: 32
      repoUrl: https://download.fedoraproject.org:/pub/fedora/linux/releases/32/Server/x86_64/os/
    - os: ubuntu
      architecture: amd64
      release: 18_04
      repoUrl: https://archive.ubuntu.com:/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/installer-amd64/
    - os: ubuntu
      architecture: i386
      release: 18_04
      repoUrl: https://archive.ubuntu.com:/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/installer-i386/
```

*vars/main.yml*

```yaml
   os: fedora
   architecture: x86_64
   release: 32
```

*tasks/main.yml*

```yaml
- name: Display os architecture release
  debug:
    msg: "os:{{ os }} architecture:{{ architecture }} release:{{ release }}"

- name: Lookup fedora x86_64 32 repoUrl
  debug:
    msg: "repoUtl:{{ fedVar.repoUrl }}"
  loop: "{{ distributionRepositoryUrl | json_query(url_query) | flatten }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: fedVar
  vars:
    url_query: "repository[?os=={{ os }} && architecture=={{ architecture }} && release=={{ release }}].{repoUrl: repoUrl}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Ansible documentation on `json_query`:

> **Note**
> Here, quoting literals using backticks avoids escaping quotes and maintains readability.

<sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter*</sup>

So your your are just missing backticks around your values in your JMESPath expression:

```yaml
url_query: "repository[?os==`{{ os }}` && architecture==`{{ architecture }}` && release==`{{ release }}`].{repoUrl: repoUrl}"
```

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    distributionRepositoryUrl:
      repository:
        - os: fedora
          architecture: aarch64
          release: 32
          repoUrl: https://download.fedoraproject.org:/pub/fedora/linux/releases/32/Server/aarch64/os/
        - os: fedora
          architecture: x86_64
          release: 32
          repoUrl: https://download.fedoraproject.org:/pub/fedora/linux/releases/32/Server/x86_64/os/
        - os: ubuntu
          architecture: amd64
          release: 18_04
          repoUrl: https://archive.ubuntu.com:/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/installer-amd64/
        - os: ubuntu
          architecture: i386
          release: 18_04
          repoUrl: https://archive.ubuntu.com:/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/installer-i386/
    
    os: fedora
    architecture: x86_64
    release: 32
  
  tasks:
    - name: Display os architecture release
      debug:
        msg: "os:{{ os }} architecture:{{ architecture }} release:{{ release }}"

    - name: Lookup fedora x86_64 32 repoUrl
      debug:
        msg: "repoUtl:{{ fedVar.repoUrl }}"
      loop: "{{ distributionRepositoryUrl | json_query(url_query) | flatten }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: fedVar
      vars:
        url_query: "repository[?os==`{{ os }}` && architecture==`{{ architecture }}` && release==`{{ release }}`].{repoUrl: repoUrl}"
```

The recap would be

```
PLAY [all] ********************************************************************************************************

TASK [Display os architecture release] ****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "os:fedora architecture:x86_64 release:32"
}

TASK [Lookup fedora x86_64 32 repoUrl] ****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'repoUrl': 'https://download.fedoraproject.org:/pub/fedora/linux/releases/32/Server/x86_64/os/'}) => {
    "msg": "repoUtl:https://download.fedoraproject.org:/pub/fedora/linux/releases/32/Server/x86_64/os/"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```